# How does the Lgr5 receptor contribute to maintaining stemness in the intestine?

Tags: cell-biology, cell-signaling, stem-cells

I don't understand the connection between Lgr5 receptor and Wnt between Paneth cells and stem cells. And how does this link to the EphB-EprinB inhibition between transit amplifying cells and differentiated cells?

My book "The molecular biology of the cell" 6th edition (Garland Science) only states that the Lgr5 receptor in the stem cells makes them able to create a mini-gut (organoid), but I am asked to present factors that makes the gut able to totally renew itself and maintain its structure.

I have already answered the Delta-Notch lateral inhibition pathway and its connection to Wnt signaling from the paneth cells in determinating differentiation and maintaining in ability to divide.